# Dimension of the intersection of two subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a vector space  with basis

B = {_1,…,_64,_1,…,_22}

Suppose that   = Span{_1,…,_64} and  = Span{_1,…,_22}.

Suppose also that you have the set ∩ = {∈|∈ and ∈}, and that it's a subspace of  .

I know that dim(V) = 86, dim(X) = 64, and dim(Y) = 22.

How do I find dim(∩)? Do I need to use the formula dim(X∩Y) = dim(X) + dim(Y) - dim(X+Y)? If so, I don't know how to obtain dim(X+Y). Or, if this is actually simple, please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $v \in X \cap Y$, $v = \lambda_1b_1+\cdots+\lambda_{64}b_{64}$ and $v = \mu_1c_1+\cdots+\mu_{22}c_{22}$ for some scalars $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$. Hence $$\lambda_1b_1+\cdots+\lambda_{64}b_{64}-\mu_1c_1-\cdots-\mu_{22}c_{22} = 0$$ and, by linear independence, then $\lambda_i=\mu_j=0$ for all $i$ and $j$. Thus $v=0$, and that means $X \cap Y = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the subspaces $X$ and $Y$ of $V$ are spanned by subsets of a basis with empty intersection, $X\cap Y=\{0\}$. Therefore, $\dim(X\cap Y)=0$.